# Sort based on related objects field in Django

Tags: python, django, sorting, django-queryset

I have two models, Player and Match

```
class Player(PlayerModel):
    points = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    games_played = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    wins = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    draws = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    defeats = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    goals_scored = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    goals_conceded = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    goal_difference = models.IntegerField(default=0)


class Match(models.Model):
    player1 = models.ForeignKey(Player, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='player1')
    player2 = models.ForeignKey(Player, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='player2')
    score1 = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    score2 = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    winner = models.ForeignKey(Player, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='winner')
```

I want to sort Player model objects based on their points, if points are equal then on goal_difference, and if goal_difference is equal then I must check to see who won the match between the players with equal points(winner field of Match object).

```
def head_to_head():
table_list = []
match = Match.objects.all()
for m in match:
    if m.player1 not in table_list:
        table_list.append(m.player1)
    if m.player2 not in table_list:
        table_list.append(m.player2)
    table_list.sort(key=lambda x: (x.points, x.goal_difference), reverse=True)
```

But I can't figure out how to sort based on head to head matches.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to compare only two players, there is only one match, and the players are guaranteed to have played against each other then I recommend taking the following match:

```py
from django.db.models import Q

def head_to_head(player1, player2):
    match = Match.objects.get(
        Q(player1=player1, player2=player2) |
        Q(player1=player2, player2=player1)
    )
    return match.winner
```

I don't know what mechanism you're using to specify the precedence of ordering operations, but this definition of `head_to_head` acts as a comparator between two players. I added the `Q` filter so that you can capture the match between the two players regardless of the ordering of how they were recorded.

To use this comparator, you could take a list of `Player` objects and use python's [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions) built-in with `head_to_head` passed in for the `key` parameter:

```py
sorted(player_list, key=head_to_head)
```

Comment: Sebastian Gaweda  thank your for answering so fast.The players play only 1 match against each other, but the thing is there can be more than 2 players with equal points, so I need to check all players with same points.And how to sort the list using this function, so if the points and goals_difference are equal, it sorts based on head_to_head match?

Comment: Consider you have 3 players: A, B, C. Then assume the matches have the following wins and losses: (A, B) -> A, (B, C) -> B, (C, A) -> C. A should be ahead of B, B should be ahead of C, and C should be ahead of A, but such an ordering is impossible. I'd reconsider using this as a way to determine order because it can only be used to break ties and cannot produce a total ordering in general.

Comment: As for how to sort the list, I've updated my answer with an example.

Comment: (A, B) -> A, (B, C) -> B, (C, A) -> C In this case, the ordering must be based on goals_scored field.

Comment: If the `goals_scored` was sufficient, then we wouldn't execute this comparison. Besides you can also consider the case where the matches all had a score of 1-0.

Comment: I mean if (A, B) -> A, (B, C) -> B, (C, A) -> C this situation happens, it must pass it, and count goals_scored in all matches, not only the matches played against the players with equal points, but all matches against every player.

Comment: But how will it detect that this cycle has occurred? The sort function won't be able to tell you that. I'm going to reiterate that you may want to reconsider using this as a way to determine order because it cannot produce a total ordering.